# Return all children where at least one exists in same parent

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to write an MDX query that I think is similar to a `where exists` in SQL. We have `Files` which are made of `SubFiles`, and every `SubFile` is in a `Location`. There's a dimension for `Locations` and a dimension for `Files` (containing a `File -> SubFile` hierarchy), and a measure count of all `SubFiles`.

So the following MDX:

```
select
    [Location].[Location].members on 0,
    [File].[File].members on 1
from
    [MyCube]
```

returns something like:

```
             | LocA | LocB | LocC | LocD
----------------------------------------
FileA        | null |  2   |   2  | null
FileB        |  1   |  2   | null | null
FileC        | null | null |   1  |  2
```

This is showing that, for eg, `FileA` has 2 `SubFiles` in `LocB` and 2 `SubFiles` in `LocC` (and none in `LocA` or `LocD`). It has 4 `SubFiles` total.

What I need to achieve is, for a given `Location` return all `SubFiles` where *at least one* `SubFile` under the same `File` is in a given `Location`. So for eg given the above example, if the given location were `LocC`, the result set should be:

```
             | LocA | LocB | LocC | LocD
----------------------------------------
FileA        |
   SubFileA1 | null | null |   1  | null
   SubFileA2 | null |   1  | null | null
   SubFileA3 | null |   1  | null | null
   SubFileA4 | null | null |   1  | null
FileC        |
   SubFileC1 | null | null | null |   1
   SubFileC2 | null | null |   1  | null
   SubFileC3 | null | null | null |   1
```

So **all** `SubFiles` for `FileA` and `FileC` are returned as they have at least 1 `SubFile` in `LocC`, whilst `FileB` is not returned as it has no `SubFiles` in `LocC`.

How can I achieve this in MDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Exists` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/exists-mdx) to get the Files, and then the [`Descendants` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/descendants-mdx) to add the sub files:

```
select
    [Location].[Location].members
    on 0,
    Descendants(
        Exists(
            [File].[File -> SubFile].[File].members, 
            {[Location].[Location].[LocC]}
        ), 
        [File].[File -> SubFile].[SubFile],
        SELF_AND_BEFORE
    )
    on 1
from
    [MyCube]
```

Comment: The `Exists` seems to return every `File` regardless of whether its in the given location or not - I get the same result set for every location, and the count is identical to if I omit it entirely. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @Kai Do you have records in your measure group/fact table for the case that the File/SubFile does not exist for a location, possibly having 0 or null as the measure value? In that case, `Exists` does not work. Do you have more than one measure group which have references to both dimensions File and Location?

Comment: All `SubFiles` exist in exactly 1 location (never 0). There are multiple measures, but the default measure is the one I'm interested in

Comment: @Kai I was not talking about measures, but measure groups. And the way `Exists` works is it looks into the data, and if there is any record in a measure group with a reference to the  Location dimension for "LocC" and a reference to the File dimension that contains the File, then these are assumed to exist together. It does not look into any measure in the measure group.